# Parse string pattern into Date in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, datetime, date

Is there some way in flex to parse strings to date. I want it to support custom formats similar to 'dateformatter'. Using 'dateformatter' class we can parse date object in various string formats as specified by 'formatString property'. I want it other way round, from string to date. The parse method 'Date.parse(my_string)' does string parsing but for a very limited set of formats. Can't we have something similar to following, where user can specify his/her own formats.

```
someformatter.formatString = 'HH::MM::SS' ;
mydate = someformatter.formatTodate('23::56:34');
```

Will 'parseDateString' method of dateformatter be useul here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
DateField.StringToDate()
```

This is static function of DateField class, and returns Date object.