# reverse date formatting in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, date, formatting, date-formatting

As3 has some functions that help with converting a date to various formats of strings, but I cannot find any functions that do the opposite.

in the case of

- `2012-04-16` I'd like to use `YYYY-MM-DD` as my format string to get a date object
- `01/01/2013 12:00.13` I would specify `DD/MM/YYYY HH:NN.SS

Is ther something that does the reverse/opposite of [formatDate](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/mx/formatters/DateFormatter.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leveraging off a similar question ([Parse string pattern into Date in Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946224/parse-string-pattern-into-date-in-flex)), you can use DateField.stringToDate to get the date portion of the string:

```
var theDate:Date
theDate = DateField.stringToDate('2012-04-16', 'YYYY-MM-DD');  // Returns 16 April 2012
theDate = DateField.stringToDate('01/02/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY');  // Returns 1 Feb 2013
```

Unfortunately this only parses the date, not the time.

There are examples of using RegExp to parse out the different date-time components and then creating the Date with the values thus parsed, but I've not seen or done anything like the generic format string approach.

Comment: thanks, I was able to take that function and add the hour, Minute and Second mask